# kivy app freezes when using threading

Tags: python, kivy

I had this code which uses threading but at some point, the GUI freezes (after I pressed the button).

```
import threading
import Queue

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

main_kv = """

<CustomLabel>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: self.texture_size


<Main>:

    orientation: "vertical"

    Button:
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: dp(70)
        on_press: root.spawn_threads()



"""



class CustomLabel(Label):
    pass



class Main(BoxLayout):

    def spawn_threads(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_something, 1)

    def job(self):
        task = self.q.get()
        self.add_widget(CustomLabel(text=str(task)))
        self.q.task_done()

    def do_something(self, *args):
        data = [i for i in xrange(20)]

        self.q = Queue.Queue()

        for i in data:
            self.q.put(i)

        for _ in xrange(20):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.job)
            t.daemon = 1
            t.start()

        self.q.join()


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(main_kv)
        return Main()


TestApp().run()
```

I've read somewhere that I must not block the GUI or else it will freeze... Maybe the "self.q.join()" is blocking the GUI. Is there another way to implement queue join() method so that I'm not blocking the GUI?

Comment: you should not create a GUI component in another thread, I recommend using the threads exclusively so as not to block the main thread.For me you are using the threads unnecessarily. What blocking task are you trying to handle?

Comment: I wanted to make a gui for a multithreaded port scanner.

Comment: Okay, but that's another thing, reading the scanner port from another thread, but not the task of creating the GUI.

Comment: You have the calculation in another thread but you must update the GUI in the main thread, check the following link: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application,

Comment: @eyllanesc. Thanks for the info and the link. I'll study it.

Comment: Yes, the `q.join` does block the GUI. It means you're not returning from the event handler until all of the background threads are done, so no other event handlers can run, so the GUI stops updatng. What you probably want to do is create another thread that does the `q.join()` or even that does the entire body of `do_something`. Some cases can get tricky, where you need a background thread to synchronize with the UI in some way, but your `do_something` doesn't touch the UI at all, so this case is trivial.

Comment: Meanwhile: is there a reason you're daemonizing the threads? Also, have you considered using a threadpool (like [`futures`](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) or [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy)) instead of building one yourself with a queue and a list of threads? (Normally, you don't actually want as many threads as tasks—or, when you do, you don't want a queue of tasks.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have two problems here.

---

First, as you surmised:

> I've read somewhere that I must not block the GUI or else it will freeze... Maybe the "self.q.join()" is blocking the GUI. Is there another way to implement queue join() method so that I'm not blocking the GUI?

You're absolutely right about the problem, but you're on the wrong track about the solution.

The reason `q.join` is blocking the GUI is that it's waiting until all of your background work is finished. You can't do that in an event callback. Until your callback returns, the entire UI is frozen, waiting for you.

There are three ways around this:

- You can spawn another thread just to wait on the queue, or even to do the entire body of `do_something`, and then just return without waiting for that thread. After all, you're not doing anything after the `q.join`, so it doesn't really matter when it happens.
- Or you could just not wait at all. Does anything need to synchronize on or otherwise respond to these threads finishing their work? It doesn't seem like it.
- Simplest of all, you could just create a persistent threadpool, using [`futures`](https://pypi.org/project/futures/) or [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) and just `submit` tasks to it here, instead of creating a new thread for each task. (You're trying to create a pool here, but you don't need a separate pool for each operation. And you rarely want as many threads as tasks—when you do, you generally don't want a pool or a queue.)

---

But if you solve that, you've still got another problem. While your `do_something` function doesn't interact with the UI, the tasks you're spawning do. And you're not allowed to interact with the UI from background threads.

To fix this one, you want to move the UI work into a [`@mainthread`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.mainthread) function:

```
@mainthread
def makelabel(self, text):
    self.add_widget(CustomLabel(text=text))

def job(self):
    task = self.q.get()
    self.makelabel(str(task))
    self.q.task_done()
```

---

But really, if the *only* thing you're doing in these background tasks is creating a widget, there's no reason to use threads in the first place. You're adding a bunch of overhead and complexity, and not getting any benefit. You want to use threads (or, again, a thread pool) if you're making a bunch of network requests, or running a bunch of subprocesses, or doing some other work that takes a while and mostly involves waiting around. Notice that the example for `@mainthread` does exactly that:

```
self.req = UrlRequest(url='http://...', on_success=callback)
```

(A [`UrlRequest`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html#kivy.network.urlrequest.UrlRequest) is a thread dedicated to making a request, waiting for the response, and then calling a callback function.)